# How to get a ODATA value from the model and display it on a message box

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have created an ODATA Call to the Northwind database, I have been playing with bindings and have some questions that I could not figure out.

In this specific example when I click Login it is going to display the value in the text box, and also open a messagebox to display the same, but the very first time i click it won't display anything. After the second time it works. 
Why is this happening?

Another question is if I can change the bind of the textbox dynamically instead of using {CompanyName} I would like to get the ContactName but when I use SETVALUE it will print the text {ContactName}. Thanks again!

https://jsbin.com/nofunecane/1/edit?html,output

```
sap.m.MessageBox.alert(this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/Customers('ALFKI')/CompanyName"));
```

This is the new code with the Success Method:
https://jsbin.com/gagajusoja/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite get what was your intention, because what you are doing in the "getLogin" function is:

1. take the Input control by id and do the element binding (to a specific customer). In the xml view you bind the value of the Input to the "CompanyName" property(relatively), that's why after clicking on "Log In" button, the input is automatically populated by the "Alfred Futterkiste" - the company name of the customer "ALFKI"
2. on the next code line, you try to get the "CompanyName" property, and getting the empty message box, which is correct because at that time binding did not load the data form the backend (because normally, all the HTTP requests are asynchronous, so you need to wait some time until the data are loaded).

In order to do so, use the [dataReceived](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Binding.html#event:dataReceived%20dataReveived) callback when [bindElement](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#bindElement).
So your function will look like this:

```
getLogin: function(evt) {
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    this.byId("txtUid").bindElement({
        path: "/Customers('ALFKI')",
        events: {
            dataReceived: function(oResponse) {
                sap.m.MessageBox.alert(oModel.getProperty("/Customers('ALFKI')/CompanyName"));
            }
        }
    });

    this.getView().getModel().read("/Customers('ANATR')", {

        success: function(oResponse) {
            sap.m.MessageBox.alert(oModel.getProperty("/Customers('ANATR')/CompanyName"));
        }

    });
}
```

As for your 2nd question, you can use [bindProperty](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html%20bindProperty) method programmatically.

Comment: Thank you! I understood the concept I just modified the bin but as you can see the popup never display, like if the success method is never called. Did I missed somemthing?

       this.getView().getModel().read("/Customers('ANATR')", {
       events: {
        success: function (oResponse) {
         sap.m.MessageBox.alert(this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/Customers('ANATR')/CompanyName"));
        }
       }
      });

https://jsbin.com/gagajusoja/edit?html,output

Comment: For my second questions, I want to replace the txtUid field value of {CompanyName} for {ContactName} but could not find to update that parameter in the txtUid with code. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer, becasue I used the wrong binding API. Now it should work. The "dataReceived" callback does the job. And in your jsBin you lost your "this" in the callback context, so either use "var that = this" technique or save the needed variables at the beginning of the function scope, like I did for "oModel".

Comment: That dataReceived is for binding and success when reading the model using READ I hope i got them right.